# Installing CakePHP 3.10 outputs version 4.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm attemping to install CakePHP 3.10 using the following command:

`composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:3.* my_app_name`

However, once it's done, I see this on the welcome page:

"Welcome to CakePHP 4.2.8 Strawberry"

Output of console:

```
$ composer create-project --prefer-dist cakephp/app:3.* my_app_name
Creating a "cakephp/app:3.*" project at "./my_app_name"
Installing cakephp/app (3.10.0)
  - Installing cakephp/app (3.10.0): Extracting archive
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there was a mistake, it seems that `3.10.0` accidentally targeted the `master` branch.

**https://github.com/cakephp/app/issues/849**